# Запускать программу для работы с файлом при двойном клике на файл

Tags: c#, winforms

Делаю программу на Windows Forms, которая работает с файлами определённого расширения.
При старте открывается диалоговое окно, где я выбираю нужный файл. Появилась идея сделать работу с файлами более одобной. При двойном клике на файл открывать его сразу в моей программе (кликнул на файл -> запустилась моя програ с уже открытым этим файлом). В Windows указал, что для таких файлов запускать мою программу. Вопрос как сделать чтобы запусченая программа получала этот файл для работы с ним, а не требовалось самому его искать?

Comment: Так путь к файлу вроде будет в аргументах запуска программы, если я не ошибаюсь

Comment: без десяти три, боже, как же я затупил, пора на боковую. 
Спасибо

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Program.cs

```
static class Program
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Главная точка входа для приложения.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        //с аргументами (пользователь открыл файл с помощью программы)
        MainForm f = null;
        if (args != null && args.Length > 0)
        {
            string fileName = args[0];
            //Существует ли файл?
            if (System.IO.File.Exists(fileName))
            {
                f = new MainForm (fileName);
            }
            //Файл не существует :(
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("File does not exist!", "Error!",
                    MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                f = new MainForm();
            }
        }
        //без аргументов
        else
        {
            f = new MainForm();
        }
        Application.Run(f);
    }
}
```

Главная форма MainForm.cs

```
    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public MainForm(string filename)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        openFile(filename);
    }

    private openFile(string filename)
    {
        //ваша логика для открытия файла
    }
```

---

Если нужна ещё и возможность перетаскивания файлов на форму, нужно завести обработчики событий DragEnter и DragDrop

```
void MainForm_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.FileDrop))
    {
        string[] files = (string[])e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop);
        if (isFileValid (files[0]))
        {
            e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy;
        }
    }
}

void MainForm_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    string[] files = (string[])e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop);
    if (isFileValid(files[0]))
    {
        e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy;
        openFile(files[0]);
    }
}

private bool isFileValid(string filename)
{
    //Проверяем, что можем принять такой файл
    // например, просто по расширению
    return Path.GetExtension(filename) == ".myextension";
}
```